# How to convert date and time only at time?

Tags: flutter, dart

I get by API such data about time and date `2021-09-05T18:16:47.790601+02:00` how can I get only hours from here?

Comment: you can use the `hour` getter like this: `int hoursOnly = myDateTime.hour;`

Comment: @AdnanAlshami Thanks for the answer. How do i convert this data from String to DateTime?

Comment: you can use `DateTime.parse("2021-09-05T18:16:47.790601+02:00");` to convert string to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the API you're getting a formatted date and want to get only the hour.

First, it would be better to you get from the API the UNIX date (if available) which has a timestamp format like this: https://www.unixtimestamp.com

Your first question would be more either:

How getting from a fromatted date a Timestamp to obtain the hour

or

How parsing the string to get the hour.

**Here the formatted method:**

*DateTime which should help you: [https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime-class.html](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/RegExp-class.html)*

Here an example:

```
final DateTime myDate = DateTime.parse('2021-09-05 18:16:47');
final int hour = myDate.hour;
final int minute = myDate.minute;
final int second = myDate.second;
print('hour: $hour');
print('minute: $minute');
print('second: $second');
```

Result:

```
hour: 18
minute: 16
second: 47
```

**Here the parsing method:**

*Substring which should help you: [enter link description here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/substring.html)*

*RegExp which should help you: [enter link description here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/RegExp-class.html)*

Here an example:

```
const String myDate = '2021-09-05T18:16:47.790601+02:00';
final String hour = myDate.substring(11, 13);
final String minute = myDate.substring(14, 16);
final String second = myDate.substring(17, 19);
final String date = RegExp(r"[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}").stringMatch(myDate).toString();
final List<String> splitDate = date.split(':');
print('hour: $hour');
print('minute: $minute');
print('second: $second');
print('date: $date');
print('split date: $splitDate');
```

Result:

```
hour: 18
minute: 16
second: 47
date: 18:16:47
split date: [18, 16, 47]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I figured out what Unix is. And he did everything with the help of him.

Answer (score 1):

For ISO8601 String you can convert with DateTime

```
  DateTime dt = DateTime.parse('2020-01-02 03:04:05');
```

then you can access what you want with `dt`